# Dutch and English version of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We a product which uses a SharePoint Foundation.
We usually installs English version of SharePoint on top of that we will add some specific languages but this time we installed the Dutch version of SharePoint Foundation, and not the English version with Dutch language pack.
So far we have always installed EN + language pack.

Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer No,

- Your site language will depend on the language selected when you create the site , and this also will be the default language of your [actions and conditions in SharePoint Designer.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/16/change-workflow-actions-language-in-sharepoint-designer/)

[image]

- Also the Central administration MUI Language will depend on the English version language of SharePoint installation on TOP, not Language Pack.
- Meanwhile, you can Change the language from Site Settings > Language Setting> Check alternate Language based on your first selection of creation the site as mentioned above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do think it makes a difference. When you run into errors in your farm, some or maybe a lot of errors will be in Dutch. It makes troubleshooting a lot harder.

From a user perspective it doesn't make any difference.